# How does the AC of ships in Ghosts of Saltmarsh interact with the optional vehicle proficiency rules from Xanathar's?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class, vehicles, ghosts-of-saltmarsh

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, there is an ability under ["Land and Water Vehicles"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#LandandWaterVehicles) (p. 82) called Vehicle Handling which allows you to add your proficiency bonus to the AC of a land/water vehicle you're piloting. That seems really good with [the new ship stat blocks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/vehicles) we've gotten for much larger ships in *Ghosts of Saltmarsh*. Does this work in the way I suspect?

Can I add my proficiency bonus to the AC of the ships *and* its parts detailed in the *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* book?

Answer (score 3):

### You can add your proficiency to the AC of the ships

If you are using the optional rule from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, you are able to sum your proficiency bonus to the ship's AC if you have proficiency with water vehicles.

Since a ship is composed by multiple components, and all types of ships don't have a single AC value for the entire vessel, you can add your proficiency bonus to its parts.

If there were separate AC values to the components and to the entire vessel, I would argue that you only add the value once – to the entire vessel's AC – but that's not the case.

By cross-referencing the information provided on water vehicles by the *Player's Handbook* and *Ghosts of Saltmarsh*, we can confirm that the rule in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* is meant to affect the ships published in the adventure.

On the page 157 of *Player's Handbook*, you will find the table for Waterborne Vehicles. It cites that the vehicles are: **Galley, Keelboat, Longship, Rowboal, Sailing ship, Warship**. All of this vehicles have stat blocks in the Appendix A of *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* (starting at page 186).